# django-cms string replacement on output

Tags: django-cms

For some django-cms site, I want to replace each occurrence of a fixed string (namely two stars in a row: "**") by another fixed string on output. When editing, it must remain the original string. The idea is, to have a very short tag for frequent use.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: For those who might ask: We want to resolve the problem of writing gender neutral texts in German language by adding a star, which links to our gender policy, to each problematic word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a [Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/):

```
pattern = "**"
replacement = """<span class="gender" title="some explanation">*</span>"""

class SubstituteMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if hasattr(response,"content"):
            response.content = response.content.replace(pattern,replacement)
        return response
```

- Modify `pattern` and `replacement` according to your needs.
- Place this code into `<yoursite>/middleware/sub.py` (add directory middleware with empty `__init__.py` if not yet present)
- Add `<yoursite>.middleware.sub.SubstituteMiddleware` to the `MIDDLEWARE`-list in `settings.py`

Note that this approach is deficient in that it replaces not only content, but also
accidentally matching parts of the HTML-code.

Comment: WIth python3, pattern and replacement have to be byte arrays, e.g.:
pattern = b"**"; replacement = b"""<span...